# Capturing user input from a powershell workflow

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
Workflow Test {
    $message = "Hey"
    InlineScript{
        Write-Output $using:message
        Read-Host 'Get user input before proceeding.'
    }
    InlineScript{
        Write-Output $using:message
    }
}

Test
```

What I get in return:

> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the
>   command type does not support user interaction.

Is there any way to tell a workflow to pause for user input before proceeding?  I'm using Workflows to support parallel foreach - but I want to pause between operations.

I could try this:

```
Workflow Test1 {
    $message = "Hey"
    InlineScript{
        Write-Output $using:message
        Read-Host 'Get user input before proceeding.'
    }
}

Workflow Test2 {
    $message = "Hey"
    InlineScript{
        Write-Output $using:message
    }
}

Test1
// wait for user input
Test2
```

But then I have repeated constants there - `$message` - which isn't very DRY.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible. Workflows can be triggered "interactively" but are expected to be run non-interactive, and often against a number of different machines all at once. The reason you even need `InlineScript` to support all PowerShell commands is because it's a different environment, so you can think of those blocks as running in a different runspace.

Comment: @briantist - I see.  I guess I could do separate workflows, but then I have to repeat all of my variable declarations in every single one, which seems really messy.  Any tips on this?  Updating question now.

Comment: If the only reason you're using a workflow is for parallelism, I'd recommend just using jobs or [PoshRsJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PowerShell Workflow is designed to run without interaction. Each workflow is scheduled as a job that runs in a seperate PowerShell instance.

Workflows are designed to be robust and parallel, and allowing input from a person in the middle of a workflow would increase the risk of something going wrong in the middle of execution.

You can pass parameters into a workflow by using the normal `param` keyword, which would allow you to get any information you need to execute the workflow up front.

```
workflow DoStuff
{
    param([string[]]$Value)

    ...
}
```

Another way to not require interactivity would be think about how you could detect when PowerShell should move on to the next operation instead of requiring a person to.